# Define interface variable with only two string hardcoded values

Tags: interface, enums, typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface ResponseFromServer {
    type:string;
    message:string;
}
```

How can I restrict the `type` variable for being only one of the two following values:

```
"success"
"error"
```

Comment: Why? I'm assuming this is an ajax response of some sort and you're doing success/error handling based on the `type` value. You can't force the server to return `success` or `error` from the client. but you **can** only handle those two type values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from 2013 is now deprecated.

It is now possible in this way:

```
interface ResponseFromServer {
    type: "success" | "error";
    message: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Types are about the shape of the data, not the content.

Comment: Mmm. Okey, there are no workaround with this? By using enums of something like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could define `enum Responses { success, error }` and change the server to only return 0 or 1.